What is the method for representing a quantum circuit from a bit equation?
I am currently studying this paper(https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9503016).
I'm having trouble effectively utilizing the content depicted in the image below from the paper.

It seems that one could derive a bit equation from the circuit above. However, I'm interested in knowing how to represent a quantum circuit when given a bit equation. Are there any textbooks, papers, or resources that can help with this?
